# Adding filtering to my mongodb while using find() in express routing possible? and how?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hello i have this GET function thats using async which finds the specific "Category" mongoose Schema the user just clicked  and another "Tool" mongoose 
Schema (which just finds all the tools in my database)and transports them both to a rendered page.

i was wandering if theres a way to add some sort of filtering to my Tool.find so it will find for example only the tools which have the same category proprety (Tool.category) as the Category (Category.name) the user just clicked?

the GET function:

```
router.get("/catalog/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    let output = {
            category: [],
            tools: []
    };
    async.parallel([
            function (cb) {
                    Category.findById(req.params.id).exec(function (err, foundCategory) {
                            if (err || !foundCategory) {
                                    req.flash("error", "No category found.");
                                    return res.redirect("back");
                            } else {
                                    output.category = foundCategory;
                                    cb(null, foundCategory);
                            }
                    });
            },
            function (cb) {
                    Tool.find({}, function (err, foundTools) {
                            if (err || !foundTools) {
                                    req.flash("error", "No tools were found.");
                                    return res.redirect("back");
                            } else {
                                    output.tools = foundTools;
                                    cb(null, foundTools);
                            }
                    });
            }
    ], function done(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                    res.json(err.message);
            } else {
                    res.render("tools/catalog-items", {
                            category: output.category,
                            tools: output.tools
                    });
            }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can do this. What you want to achieve is to make the second query dependent on the results of the first one.

In this case, `async.parallel` is not going to work as you need to get the result of `Category.findById` first.

If you'd have multiple (more than 2) subsequent queries I'd suggest you the `async.waterfall` method. You can see the docs [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall).

But for this particular case, you can go as simple as this:

```js
Category.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundCategory) {
    if (err || !foundCategory) {
        req.flash("error", "No category found.");
        return res.redirect("back");
    }

    Tools.find({
        // As described in the question we filter by a `name` field
        // although in future you might consider creating an ObjectId reference
        category: foundCategory.name
    }, function (err, foundTools) {

        // As we applied filtering we might return an empty array of tools
        // instead of throwing an error
        if (err || !foundTools) {
            req.flash("error", "No tools were found.");
            return res.redirect("back");
        }

        res.render("tools/catalog-items", {
            category: foundCategory,
            tools: foundTools
        });
    });
});
```

You can definitely do the sorting as well. You just need to add `.sort({someProperty: 1}).exec(...)`. See the examples [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).